# Using php to convert a number to number format with oop methods

Tags: php, oop

If I have a function, e.g. to convert a number to a number format, I obviously want it to take `any` input var and to return a change to that `same` input var. However, the below isn't working and I'm not sure why. I understand how to use number_format etc, but I don't get how it fits with **OOP**:

```
Class generic{

public function numeric($num){
    if(!is_numeric($num) && !is_float($num)){
        throw new Exception("Inputed number is not numeric.");
    }

    //Convert the input to a number format
    $this->num = number_format($num,2);  
    echo $this->num; // shows a number in the new format..

    //Return the input with its new value
    $num = $this->num;

    return $num;

    }
  }


 class someother class {

  //function receiving an array and processing the numbers from it.
 public function display_info($data) {

        foreach($data->listing as $item) {
           $price = $price+$item->price;
        } 
             echo $price; //this shows a number in original format.
                    //Process $price through the generic class 'numeric' function
        generic::numeric($price);

        echo '<br/>Total:'.$price.'<br/>'; //This also shows the original format

                    $output = $this->someotherfunction($price);

        return $output;
        }

 public function someotherfunction($data) {
 //Manipulate the data
 return $data;
 }
   }



   //Create a new display object to process the pre-existing array $data
   $test = new someother();
   //Process an array containing 
   $test->display_info($data);
```

If you can help me to  understand this I'd be really grateful.

How does `$this->num = $num vs $num = $this->num` work?

Comment: You recieve $num as param, modify it through the method body, and return the new value, without modifying the object context (`$this->num`). But still I don't think it will work without assignation `$price = generic::numeric($price)`

Comment: You have scope and reference confusions, plus you cant call an instance method with a static call

Comment: I get that in principle... but I'm really struggling to get my head around it. $this->num = number_format($num,2); seems to be the bit that works for converting it to the new value. Should I try to avoid using $this->num inside a function? Thanks!

Comment: @Simeon $this->num is from the object of type `Generic`, so it will modify `$num` from the current object, but not from `MyOtherClass`

Comment: @RoyalBg Ahh. That is a really helpful - I included the 2 classes as I wondered if that was something to do with it. Is it better to use self::num in that case or something else?

Comment: The reason I was hoping to avoid using `$price = generic::numeric($price)` is that I've got a lot of different numbers in the array that I want to convert to number format and add to an array - If I have to do $price = for each of them it feels like it would take longer to do.

Comment: See my edit regarding pass by reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Generic {
    private $num;

    public function __construct($num) {
        $this->num = $num;
    }

    public function numeric() {
        if(!is_numeric($this->num) && !is_float($this->num)){
            throw new Exception("Inputed number is not numeric.");
        }
        $this->num = number_format($this->num,2);  
        return $this;
    }

    public function value() {
        return $this->num;
    }
}

class OtherClass {

    private static function setNum($num) {
        return new Generic($num);
    }

    public function display_info() {
        $price = self::setNum(100);
        echo '<br/>Total:'.$price->numeric()->value().'<br/>';
    }
}




   $test = new OtherClass();
   $test->display_info();
```

If you really want to keep object oriented programming, but I don't think numeric interactions are OOP closed, however what I have done here.

You `Generic` class holds a number, which you modify bu several method, in this case we have only `numeric()` method.

In your `display` method you call this class, and set it the value of the price, II hardcoded `100` but it could be whatever numeric value you want.

As the `numeric()` method modifies the `$this->num` from its object, and return its instance you can call `value()` method which will return the new modified value.

- Once you set value to the class
- Then you modify it by a method (`numeric()`)
- Then you pass the `value()` to the echo

The output is:

> Total:100.00

---

The example from my comment:

```
class Generic {
    private $num;
    private $normalized;

    public function __construct($num) {
        $this->num = $num;
        $this->normalized = $num;
    }

    public function numeric() {
        if(!is_numeric($this->num) && !is_float($this->num)){
            throw new Exception("Inputed number is not numeric.");
        }
        $this->num = number_format($this->num,2);  
        return $this;
    }

    public function toInt() {
        $this->num = intval($this->num);
        return $this;
    }

    public function printR() {
        echo "<pre>".print_r($this->num, true)."</pre>";
    }

    /**
     * As normalized was set to the original value of $num and was not modified,
     * you will recieve what you have put from the beginning to the constructor
     */
    public function normalize() {
        $this->num = $this->normalized;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * You can use this method to retrieve the original value (without calling normalize())
     * And you will still have the modified $num, if you want to use it
     */
    public function originalValue() {
        return $this->normalized;
    }

    public function value() {
        return $this->num;
    }

}

class OtherClass {

    private static function setNum($num) {
        return new Generic($num);
    }

    public function display_info() {
        $price = self::setNum(100);

        /**
         * numeric() changes it with number_format()
         * <pre>100.00</pre>
         */
        $price->numeric()->printR();

        /**
         * toInt() changes it to integer
         * <pre>100</pre>
         */
        $price->toInt()->printR();


        $price->numeric();

        /**
         * The original value is still kept
         * 100
         */
        echo $price->originalValue();
        /**
         * But the object is changed (because of numeric() call)
         * 100.00
         */
        echo $price->value();


        $price->normalize();

        /**
         * After being normalized to the original value
         * 100
         */
        echo $price->value();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - OOP is much more complicated than I thought... I had put a few other generic functions in the generic class (i.e. print_r / pre) - with the thought that these functions would be useful for all classes (of which I'd made about 5). From this it seems like I should have had about 20 classes instead. Is there a rule of thumb for when to create a new class?

Comment: @Simeon put the functions in this generic class, there's no problem. You can change the state of the object as I have shown with the `numeric()` method. And printing functions will just print, without change for example.

Comment: I edited to show examples. But still I see for numbers you don't need to make that much logic, maybe a helper class with return value and static functions is enough (someone could consider it bad design ).

Comment: That is so helpful!! I'm playing around with it and putting functions inside at the moment. Would it be right to say that, in terms of an MVC framework `otherClass->display_info()` is most like the view and the `generic` class the model? And that if I found a way to inject in to `$price = self::setNum(100);` with a user defined entry it would be a controller? Thank you so much.

Comment: In the way of MVC - `OtherClass` is Controller and `Generic` is Helper. `View` is the way where `OtherClass` is instantiated (i.e. when you access `mysite.com/other/`, the template file will be aware of the object. It really depends on your route settings, though :). To Inject user input you should use one of the request methods i.e. post `$price = self::setNum($_POST['userNumInputField']);`. Tbh, in the terms of MVC each method from the controller is called by action i.e. `mysitte.com/other/display_info` will fire `$obj = new OtherClass()` and call `$obj->display_info()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand scope, and how variables are passed in php.
The function in your generic class is passed a COPY of the price variable - no changes this function makes effects the original price var in the someother object.

To do what you want:

```
Class generic{

    //must be static to be called statically
    public static function numeric($num){
        if(!is_numeric($num) && !is_float($num)){
            throw new Exception("Inputed number is not numeric.");
        }
        return number_format($num,2);

    }
}

class someothere{

    //function receiving an array and processing the numbers from it.
    public function display_info($data) {

        foreach($data->listing as $item) {
            $price = $price+$item->price;
        }
        //the generic::numeric function RETURNS a value, it does NOT modify the original
        echo '<br/>Total:'.generic::numeric($price).'<br/>';

    }
}
```

If you did, for some reason, want the function to effect the original price variable, you would need to pass it by reference:

```
Class generic{

    //must be static to be called statically
    //notice the & symbol that means that a refernce rather than a copy is passed
    public static function numeric(&$num){
        if(!is_numeric($num) && !is_float($num)){
            throw new Exception("Inputed number is not numeric.");
        }
        //edits the original variable, no need to return anything
        $num = number_format($num,2);

    }
}

class someothere{

    //function receiving an array and processing the numbers from it.
    public function display_info($data) {

        foreach($data->listing as $item) {
            $price = $price+$item->price;
        }
        generic::numeric($price);//price is now editied

        echo '<br/>Total:'.$price.'<br/>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow - This is much simpler than I'd thought. I'll try it now.